# Is "I have posted the letter last week" grammatical?

Tags: present-perfect, auxiliary-verbs, past-simple

Is this sentence grammatically OK? Take a look at this sentence:

> I have certainly posted the letter last week. I wonder why it hasn't arrived yet.

So what is the problem with this sentence?
I took a look at the answer sheet. At the first part of the sentence, the modal verb "have" is incorrect. What's your idea?

Answer (score 4):

Because the present perfect is incompatible with an explicit time reference to a period that is finished.

If the time period is still continuing, then either the simple past or the present perfect is possible:

> I have certainly posted the letter this week.
>
> I certainly posted the letter this week.

(The difference is in how the speaker is choosing to characterise the temporal relationships - the first emphasises that "this week" is continuing, and chooses to see the posting as an event that is relevant to the present. The simple past treats the posting as a finished action, ignoring the fact that it is located in a time period which encompasses the present).

But with "last week", only the simple past is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Last week is finished. You need simple past tense: I certainly posted the letter last week.

Btw. Have isn't a modal verb. It's an auxiliary in the present perfect structure.